# Change content heading text color in homepage

Tags: magento

I am starting up with **Magento**.

Trying to change color of content heading to red.

I have updated *cms_page* table like below using HTML tags:

[image]

It is being shown on page like below:

[image]

Color is not changed.Text is being shown as it is, with tags.

How can I set color for content heading?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the tag isn't good. 
If you want to style inline you should use something like:

```
<p style="color:red">New Content Heading</p>
```

Although i would strongly recommend to style via less files
Hope this helps you!

Comment: This didn't work, showing `<p style="color:red">New Content Heading</p>` on page.

Comment: Did you tried adding this from admin, and not from db?

Comment: I tried it from DB.
Let me check where can this be added in admin panel.

Comment: In the cms page you have the contend heading field. If it doesn't work like this, my best bet is to change its color through less file

Comment: I have just started playing with Magento.
Let me find the .less file and go with changes there.